# Plotting continuous variable in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am using `fplot()` to plot the expression `exp(-t)sin(5t)` over the range of `(-2,2)`. I did `fplot(exp(-t)*sin(5*t),[2,2])` but it doesn't plot the way I wanted. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting an error:

> Invalid expression. Check for missing multiplication operator, missing or unbalanced delimiters, or other syntax error.

Listen to the error - you are missing multiplication operators! We improve the code a little...

```
fplot(exp(-t).*sin(5.*t),[2,2])
```

Now you get a new error:

> Unrecognized function or variable 't'.

Again listen to the error, you haven't defined `t`, and `fplot` expects you to pass a function (from the [docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fplot.html))

> fplot(f) plots the curve defined by the **function** y = f(x)

We can make the expression into a function and improve the code a little more...

```
fplot(@(t)exp(-t).*sin(5.*t),[2,2])
```

Now you get a blank figure?? Ah looking at the docs again, we see

> fplot(f,xinterval) plots over the specified interval. Specify the interval as a two-element vector of the form [xmin xmax].

Where `[xmin xmax]` are currently both `2` in your example. We can't plot over a range of nothing, so choose something else. Now we have working code:

```
fplot(@(t)exp(-t).*sin(5.*t),[-2,2])
```

[image: plot]

Comment: @BenVoigt typo copy/pasting from different iterations of my code, in this case `5*t` involves a scalar and a vector so `*` and `.*` are equivalent. The element-wise `.*` is required for the vector-vector operation between `exp` and `sin` so I've now used it everywhere for consistency

Comment: @BenVoigt It really makes zero functional difference, but I've edited again nonetheless...